# Javascript or Jquery - on Checkbox Click, how do I change the parent-element's background color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

`onclick`, I need to

1. Locate the parent element
2. Change its background color to red

I'm having particular difficulty with the first part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.grid input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

**UPDATE** (for attribute use)

```
function clickHandler() {
    $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'red');
}
```

and then `onclick='clickHandler()'`

Comment: Is there a way to just name this function something, so that I can set the following attribute on my checkbox?   onclick="MyFunc"

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The cell now turns red when the checkbox is clicked, and turns back to white when the save button is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

if you attach the event with jquery it's pretty easy

```
$('#yourid').click(function(){
     var parent = $(this).parent();
     parent.css("background-color", "red");
});
```

Comment: I'm a little stuck, because I don't know my checkbox's ID due to the use of a GridView. Is there some way to name the function so that I can utilize the following attribute on my checkbox?  onclick="MyFunc"